# Printing two or more strings in vertical form in java

Tags: java, string

Please help me generate a program that will prompt the user to enter 2 strings and display them vertically. The output must be like this:

```
Enter 1st and 2nd String:
First
Second

F  S
i  e
r  c
s  o
t  n
   d
```

The attempted code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyCode
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        String input = in.nextLine();
        String input1=in.nextLine();
        int i =0;
        int j=0;

        for(i = 0,j=0; i < input.length()||j<input1.length(); i++,j++) {
            char letter = input.charAt(i);
            char letter1=input1.charAt(j);
            System.out.println(letter + " "+letter1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh im sorry i forgot to write =).... it is in java...please help. ive used for loop but it doesnt work

Comment: Can you show what you tried, and explain in what way it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in 0..max(length(s1),length(s2))-1:
    print " " if i >= length(s1) else s1[i];
    print " "
    print " " if i >= length(s2) else s2[i];
    print "\n"
```

Comment: am i gonna add this as it is???? sorry=) im new at this i still dont know much about java....can you give me a whole source code... your help is appreciated =)

Comment: This isn't any particular language; at the time of writing, you hadn't specified a language.

Comment: You want a single loop, and use that index for both strings.  As w/ my pseudocode above, you'll need to check for each index if that value is in each string before printing, and print a space instead if it is not.  Something like "if i < achar.length System.out.print(a char[i]) else System.out.print(" ");".  ANd don't print a "\n" between the characters; that's a newline.

Comment: i still have difficulty developing it =( can any one show me a whole source code it is in java programming..... im still learning and i am not yet that familiar with java

Comment: Still waiting to see how far you've gotten

Comment: </br>I've used single for  loop and it actually displayed 2 strings vertically but the problem is.. if the string is longer than the other there comes the error.....

Comment: @xaia: Instead of blindly getting each character to assign to letter/letter1, for each, if the index is too big, assign the variable a space instead (this is what the print...if...else was doing in my pseudo-code).  Alternately, keep your loop as is, but change it to continue while BOTH I & j are small enough.  Then, just print the remaining part of the longer string.

Answer (score 0):

If you still haven't got the solution.

1. Find the string with max length (`input` or `input1`)
2. Iterate to that max length and print the data.
3. If the two strings are not having the same length, there will be a point where the `charAt` method will not be having a specific index. So before calling the `charAt` method, always check whether the current index is less than the respective string's length, if not then just print an empty space `' '`.

Comment: Sorry that I answered it so late. I didn't check the time when the question was asked. It just came into my feed today and I answered it.

Answer (score 0):

Be simple!

1. Find the word with the max length
2. In the loop print the `i`th character
3. In case given word's length is less than `i`, then print `space`.

```java
public static void printVertical(List<String> words) {
    int max = words.stream().mapToInt(String::length).max().orElse(0);

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < max; i++, j = 0) {
        for (String word : words) {
            if (j++ != 0)
                System.out.print(' ');

            if (i < word.length())
                System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
            else
                System.out.print(' ');
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straight forward in Java.

```java
void print() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] stringA = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
    char[] stringB = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
    scanner.close();
    char A, B;
    int length = Math.max(stringA.length, stringB.length);
    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        A = index < stringA.length ? stringA[index] : ' ';
        B = index < stringB.length ? stringB[index] : ' ';
        System.out.printf("%s %s%n", A, B);
    }
}
```